# Facebook applink in call to action button not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-app-settings

I have developed an application i.e. Healthy Routine [play store link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he77G.png)

Now i create a fb page and want to enable call-to action button. I filled all the information like app link and package name for Android Section.
app link(deep link) is

`healthyroutine://home`

and i have added the functionality to handle this scheme and tested locally(By sending intent from terminal using adb).

```
.\adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "healthyroutine://home" com.healthy.routine
```

But when i am clicking on Use App button(facebook application Android),
i am navigating to screen where i am getting option to test button link. When i clicked that button my application is not opening.

[image: Facebook page in Android App]

[image]

Please help me to sort out this problem as i am scratching my mind. I have gone through all the link of creating app link using facebook hosting api (as i don't have a web site for the application).
[app link using facebook hosting api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api)

Thanks in Advance!!